# Javascript: iterate through object with recursion to build navigation list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, navigation

How can i build a multilevel navigation with the following object.

```
var obj = {
    1:{
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1"
    },
    2:{
        title: "title2",
        link: "link2",
        1:{
            title: "title21",
            link: "link21"
        },
        2:{
            title: "title22",
            link: "link22"
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get the following result, but i am getting doubles back because of the two object properties inside each object. See working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vzv2yy6s/) here.

```
function menuWalker(obj) {
    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var property in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            html += '<li>';
            console.log(obj[property]);
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object"){
                html += '<a href="' + obj[property].link + '">' + obj[property].title + '</a>';
                html +=  menuWalker(obj[property]);
            }else{
                html += '<a href="' + obj.link + '">' + obj.title + '</a>';
            }
            html += '</li>';
        }
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}
```

Current Html result:

- title1

  - title1
  - title1
- title2

  - title21

    - title21
    - title21
  - title22

    - title22
    - title22
  - title2
  - title2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control the structure of the navigation data, you can implement Nerdwood's answer.

But if you don't have the control, you can try:

## **Walker**

```
function menuWalker(obj) {
    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof obj[property] == "object") {
            html += '<li>' + childrenMenuWalker(obj[property]) + '</li>';
        }
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}

function childrenMenuWalker(obj) {
    var html = '';
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('title') && obj.hasOwnProperty('link')) {
        html += '<a href="' + obj.link + '">' + obj.title + '</a>';
    }

    var hasChildren = false;
    var childrenHtml = '<ul>';
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof obj[property] == "object") {
            hasChildren = true;
            childrenHtml += '<li>' + childrenMenuWalker(obj[property]) + '</li>';
        }
    }
    childrenHtml += '</ul>';

    if (hasChildren) {
        html += childrenHtml;
    }

    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the structure of the navigation data, I would suggest the following. This way you are specifically defining if a navigation item has child items or not, and makes everything much clearer.

### Data

```
var obj = [
    {
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1",
        children: []
    },
    {
        title: "title2",
        link: "link2",
        children: [
            {
                title: "title21",
                link: "link21"
            },
            {
                title: "title22",
                link: "link22"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

### Walker

```
function menuWalker(obj) {
    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var property in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            html += '<li>';
            html += '<a href="' + obj[property].link + '">' + obj[property].title + '</a>';
            if (obj[property].children && obj[property].children.length > 0){
                html +=  menuWalker(obj[property].children);
            }
            html += '</li>';
        }
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}
```

Comment: You are right, i changed the structure for a better and clearer result and  youre walker worked great on this, thanks! However i have to give the credits to Gunawan because he deliverd a solution for the problem specified so that others can benifit from this too..